# White Screen of Death on Chrome

Tags: 7, wsod

So I'm getting a white screen of death on my newly created Drupal 7 site that was working fine until a minute ago. This is only happening on Chrome, the site works fine on IE and FF.

**On chrome, the console gives the following error message:**

> net::ERR_INCOMPLETE_CHUNKED_ENCODING

**What I've done recently that might be causing this error:**

- I enabled the xmlsitemap module
- I enabled clean url's on my site - maybe this is being caused by something wrong in my .htaccess file?

**My cPanel Error log reports the following, though I'm not sure these are related issues:**

```
[Thu Sep 24 20:10:33 2015] [error] [client xx.xxx.xx.xx] File does not exist: /home/myuser/public_html/sites/default/files/milla.jpg, referer: http://mydomain.fi/?q=node/7/edit&destination=admin/content

[Thu Sep 24 20:09:04 2015] [error] [client xx.xxx.xx.xx] File does not exist: /home/myuser/public_html/admin, referer: http://mydomain.fi/?q=admin/structure/types/manage/blog-post&destination=admin/config/search/xmlsitemap/settings

[Thu Sep 24 20:00:07 2015] [error] [client xx.xxx.xx.xx] File does not exist: /home/myuser/public_html/admin

[Thu Sep 24 19:59:59 2015] [error] [client xx.xxx.xx.xx] File does not exist: /home/myuser/public_html/admin

[Thu Sep 24 19:59:48 2015] [error] [client xx.xxx.xx.xx] File does not exist: /home/myuser/public_html/admin
```

First real Drupal project that I'm actually hosting somewhere, and now that I just got it up and running it's all coming crashing down :(

Comment: Check your PHP error and Apache error log.

Comment: Where can I find those? I checked /var/log but it's empty

Answer (score 1):

Well, I found a solution from here: 
http://www.zyxware.com/articles/3424/solved-drupal-boost-drupal-site-not-working-in-chrome-and-getting-a-blank-white-screen-when-boost-is-enabled

I added the following line to my .htaccess file:

```
Header set Cache-Control "no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0"
```

Still occasionally getting the same error message in the console, but at least now the site is loading :)

Comment: Make sure it works without Boost and no funniness in .htaccess first.

Answer (score 0):

Try to copy .htaccess file from Drupal's distributive to /home/myuser/public_html/ (may be .htaccess is absent now)

Try "/home/myuser/public_html/?q=admin" (may be clean url isn't supported) and then switch off "clean-url" setting

Comment: thanks for the tip, but still not working...